# Sending File via HTTPS Post to Server: r.text issues/ Unable to locate file

Tags: python, https, python-requests

Please forgive me, I am very new to these sort of things and am working through each issue step by step. In short, using python and the requests library, I am trying to send a file to the server. Please note, this server is not directly controlled by me, it is a research server on a University campus. It seems that it is posted properly (no error messages), here is the code:

```
 files={'upload_file': open('secretpath.txt','rb')}

 try:
    r=requests.post(url,cert=cert,files=files,verify=False)
 except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    r="No Response"
    print(r)
```

But when I run r.text to verify it was successful I get the following message:

```
'<!DOCTYPE>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Under 
 Construction</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<p>This page is under construction. 
  Please come back soon!</p>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

This indicates to me that the post was NOT successful, or does this indicate that the server is not configurated properly?

As a secondary question, when I post the file, it should be accessible via PuTTY or WinSCP correct? Or where does it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post your separate questions as separate questions.

Answer to first: check r.status_code for ‘success’. If it’s 200, all is good.

I’m guessing it is, and that html is what the server returned. Sounds like whatever is running on your server is under construction, or that you may be using the wrong URL/path.

Comment: Yes the status code is 200. So in terms of your statement "under construction", does this mean at it's current state is cannot accept the post?

Comment: Nope. It means that someone wrote an html file that says that and told the server to return it to post requests at that endpoint. 200 means the plumbing is working fine

Comment: Of course, I will when I am able to (7 minutes from now)